# pgmpy, BayesianModel: How to get probability for a given sample

Tags: python-3.x, bayesian, bayesian-networks, pgmpy

I am using the pgmpy package in python. I used the BayesianModelSampler class to sample from a BayesianModel that represents a joint distribution over multiple discrete variables.

I would like to get the probability for a given sample. Is there a way to do that ?

Thanks.